# Why are Chrome and Firefox rendering z-index differently?

Tags: css

I have an a-element with z-index -2 and a div-element with z-index -1. I expect the div-element to be on top because it has a higher z-index. In Chrome this is not the case.
Is this a bug in Google Chrome?

Edit: Please don't send suggestions on how to fix it. I want to know why it is looking different.

```css
#bar
{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    height:100px;
    z-index:-2;
    background:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}

#square
{
    position:relative;
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    z-index:-1;
    background:black;
    margin:200px auto 10000px auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body onload="document.getElementById('bar').click()">
        <a id="bar" href="#square">scroll down</a>
        <div id="square"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csaUK.png)

Comment: I vote for a bug, the huge margin seems to be the culprit but not sure why

Comment: it will be ok if you use `margin:99px auto ..` and the issue start when using `margin:100px auto ..` ... if the margin-top is bigger than the height of the fixed element it breaks

Comment: May I suggest just removing the `z-index` of `#square`, this w'll make it all work.

Comment: Please don't send suggestions on how to fix it. I want to know why it is looking different.

Answer (score -1):

To be honest im not sure why this is happening, but if you use positive values everything works as expected.

```css
#bar
{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    height:100px;
    z-index:1;
    background:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}

#square
{
    position:relative;
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    z-index:2;
    background:black;
    margin:200px auto 10000px auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body onload="document.getElementById('bar').click()">
        <a id="bar" href="#square">scroll down</a>
        <div id="square"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with the fixed position element which has more priority than other element refer [Stacking Contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) for more info

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7vmok5jz/) link with different approach to solve the problem

```
#bar
{
    position:sticky;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100vw;
    height:100px;
    z-index:-2;
    background:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}

#square
{
    position:relative;
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    z-index:-1;
    background:black;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Comment: where we can read about *that priority* in the link you shared?

Comment: stacking contexts provided link in the answer. Stacking context is complicated better use positive index value for #square

Comment: I know about stacking context but i want to know where (in the link your provided) I can find that *the fixed position element which has more priority*?